# Is Jackson Serialization of this string possible without custom serializer?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialize a JSON-String I receive as a POJO, for further usage in my code, but I am struggling to get it working without writing a custom serializer.

I would **prefer** as solution **without** writing a custom serializer, but if that is the only possible way I will write one.

*Additionally I believe the data I receive is a weird JSON since the list I request is not sent as list using `[]` but rather as a object using `{}`.*

I receive the following list/object (shortened):

```
{
    "results": {
        "ALL": {
            "currencyName": "Albanian Lek",
            "currencySymbol": "Lek",
            "id": "ALL"
        },
        "XCD": {
            "currencyName": "East Caribbean Dollar",
            "currencySymbol": "$",
            "id": "XCD"
        },
        "EUR": {
            "currencyName": "Euro",
            "currencySymbol": "â?¬",
            "id": "EUR"
        },
        "BBD": {
            "currencyName": "Barbadian Dollar",
            "currencySymbol": "$",
            "id": "BBD"
        },
        "BTN": {
            "currencyName": "Bhutanese Ngultrum",
            "id": "BTN"
        },
        "BND": {
            "currencyName": "Brunei Dollar",
            "currencySymbol": "$",
            "id": "BND"
        }
    }
}
```

I created my first POJO for the inner object like this:

```
public class CurrencyDTO implements Serializable {

  private String currencyName;
  private String currencySymbol;
  private String currencyId;


  @JsonCreator
  public CurrencyDTO( @JsonProperty( "currencyName" ) String currencyName, @JsonProperty( "currencySymbol" ) String currencySymbol,
                      @JsonProperty( "id" ) String currencyId )
  {
    this.currencyId = currencyId;
    this.currencyName = currencyName;
    this.currencySymbol = currencySymbol;
  }
}
```

which itself is fine. Now I wrote another POJO as a wrapper for the data a layer above which looks like this:

```
public class CurrencyListDTO implements Serializable {

  private List<Map<String, CurrencyDTO>> results;

  public CurrencyListDTO()
  {
  }

}
```

Adding the annotations @JsonAnySetter or using the @JsonCreator didn't help either, so I removed them again and now I am wondering which little trick could enable the correct serialization of the json.

My Exception is the following:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{"results":{"ALL":{"currencyName":"Albanian Lek","currencySymbol":"Lek","id":"ALL"},"XCD":{"currencyName":"East Caribbean Dollar","currencySymbol":"$","id":"XCD"},"EUR":{"currencyName":"Euro","currencySymbol":"â?¬","id":"EUR"},"BBD":{"currencyName":"Barbadian Dollar","currencySymbol":"$","id":"BBD"},"BTN":{"currencyName":"Bhutanese Ngultrum","id":"BTN"},"BND":{"currencyName":"Brunei Dollar","currencySymbol":"$","id":"BND"},"XAF":{"currencyName":"Central African CFA Franc","id":"XAF"},"CUP":{"cur"[truncated 10515 chars]; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.nico.Banking.api.data.dto.CurrencyListDTO["results"])
```

Comment: You should just use `Map<String, CurrencyDTO>` instead of `List<Map<String, CurrencyDTO>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your `CurrencyListDTO` to:

```
public class CurrencyListDTO {
    private Map<String, CurrencyDTO> results;
    // getters and setters
}
```

Because the `results` field in the response object is another object with the `currencyId` as key and no array.

You then can create your list of currencies like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CurrencyListDTO result = mapper.readValue(json, CurrencyListDTO.class);
List<CurrencyDTO> currencies = new ArrayList<>(result.getResults().values());
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `CurrencyListDTO` should look like below. `results` property is a `JSON Object` which should be mapped directly to `Map`. You can convert it to `Collection` using `keySet` or `values` methods.

```
class CurrencyListDTO implements Serializable {

    private Map<String, CurrencyDTO> results;

    public Map<String, CurrencyDTO> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(Map<String, CurrencyDTO> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CurrencyListDTO{" +
                "results=" + results +
                '}';
    }
}
```